# How to achieve SXA styling button and styling option on custom component?

Tags: sxa

We are trying to create custom component using `SXA 1.6` on `Sitecore 9.0.1`.

Component is finally also shown on toolbox but we are struggling to have SXA Styling button on it.

Something similar to this one:
[image: SXA Styling]

Component inherites 'StandardController' as all SXA components should and custom Sitecore template also inherits from IStyling template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button is defined in the `core` database here `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons/Edit grid parameters`. As you can see it's in the Default Rendering Buttons section so it should be available on all renderings.

Regarding sections in the Control properties dialogue. You can take a look at e.g.: Page Content rendering:

[image]

You can assign custom Control Properties templates on the renderings items like here:

[image]

Comment: Cool. I just tried and it works. Thanks for help!