# How to enable the SXA "Edit style and behavior of the component" button in a custom component?

Tags: sxa

I'm following the documentation about how to create a custom SXA rendering (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/walkthrough--building-a-simple-rendering.html) and everything is advancing smoothly.

Now that I have my custom SXA rendering, I was wondering why **it does not have the super cool "Edit style and behavior of the component"**, which is pretty handy when an author wants to change how the page is organized without having to use a bunch of splitters (which is not recommended by the way).

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your 'super cool "Edit style and behavior of the component" ' part of your question correctly, but are you looking for rendering variant? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-rendering-variant.html

Comment: What about if I don't want a variant but still want the cool button? (check my screen-shot)

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/how-to-achieve-sxa-styling-button-and-styling-option-on-custom-component